# how to display search term in the template full site editor

Tags: theme-development, templates

i am building a template for the search page (in full site editing, therefore html and no php), and i want to have a search results heading. i have this:

```
    <!-- wp:group {"layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group">
    <!-- wp:heading {"level":1} -->
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <!-- /wp:heading -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

now i have 2 issues:

1- how do i get the search term to display it?

2- how can i translate the "Search Results" string?

Comment: I think for now, you'd want to use a custom shortcode which returns the inner HTML/content for the heading (e.g. `Search Results for <search query>` with translation/gettext applied), and then use `<h1>[your-shortcode]</h1>`.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. i use return __('Search Results: ','gutrs') . the_search_query(); the string appear at the right place, but the search term appear after the body tag

Comment: That's because the function you used (`the_search_query()`) echo the output instead of returning it, hence the output was misplaced. Anyway, I reposted my comment as an answer, so I hope that's more helpful? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a core way to do that in WordPress 5.9 ..

So for now, you can use a custom shortcode which returns the inner HTML/content for the heading (e.g. `Search Results for <search query>` with translation/gettext applied), and then use `<h1>[your-shortcode]</h1>` in your template.

Here's a sample shortcode function that you can try:

```php
add_shortcode( 'your-shortcode', function () {
    /* translators: %s: Search query/keyword. */
    return sprintf(
        __( 'Search Results for "%s"', 'text-domain' ),
        esc_attr( get_search_query() )
    );
} );
```

You can also create another shortcode which returns just the search query, if you want to, but remember that you should use [`get_search_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/) and **not** [`the_search_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_search_query/) which echo the output, hence the former should be used in shortcode function which generally should not echo anything.

Comment: thanks so much. sorry it took me long, was on a long weekend

Answer (score 0):

There now is a official core way to do this https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/42662

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255057)